# когда запускаю код:

Tags: python, telebot, sublime-text

когда запускаю код:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, Dispatcher
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

updater = None

def start_bot():
    global updater
    updater = Updater(
        '5193828386:AAHWl2QUJY-EBeTyc5ms-FftV6R41tbd6FQ', use_context=True)

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

start_bot()
```

программа пишет:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Bot", line 1, in 
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, Dispatcher
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telegram'

pip install python-telegram-bot установлен

работаю в Sublime Text

Comment: Как ты думаешь, для чего программа это "выдаёт"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте, установлен ли `python-telegram-bot` на интерпретаторе, который выбран в качестве интерпретатора проекта.

В *PyCharm* можно проверь это по следующему пути:
`File -> Settings -> Project: *название проекта* -> Python Interpreter`

Comment: Привет, спасибо за ответ но как это сделать на Sublime Text?

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + P (должен открыться Package Control) -> Remove Package